# Why are my headphones disappearing from Playback devices

Tags: usb, windows-10, audio, drivers, speakers

When I start my computer, my headphones are set as the default playback device.  About 15 seconds after I log into my profile, the headphones make a quick static type sound, and no longer exist in the playback devices.  I do have **Show Disabled Devices** and **Show Disconnected Devices** checked, and my headphones definitely aren't listed.  It makes my speakers set to default after the headphones disappear.  If I restart the computer, the headphones exist again, and I can run the sound test on them, and they work fine.  I can run anything in those 15 seconds, and the headphones work fine.  If I plug these headphones into any other computer, they work fine.

I'm using the USB connection for these headphones, and I have the usb drivers installed for the mobo.  I have no idea what else to try.

Here's my hardware/software

**OS** - Windows 10

**Headphones** - Kingston Hyper-X Cloud II

**Speakers** - Just some old speakers

**Mobo** - Asus Maximus VIII Hero

I have removed all other software that messes with sound options (I think), so it's all controlled by my OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like it might be a driver crash, I use a USB sound card with my headphones and the same thing happens to me on rare occasions.

My first suggestion would be to entirely remove any drivers for the headphones (I expect if they are USB they will have drivers), then reinstall the correct driver ***for your OS*** - not to say you didn't, it's simply very important.

There are ways to go about debugging this further if this doesn't work, but I will not list them unless necessary.